# maximum independent set in graphs with small number of edges

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, independent-set

For the classic maximum independent set problem, a hardness of approximation result of $n^{1-\varepsilon}$ is known by [Hastad, 1996] assuming $\textsf{NP} \not \subseteq \textsf{ZPP}$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. Moreover, if the graph is sparse, where the degree of each vertex is bounded by $d$, the problem cannot be approximated to a better factor than $\Omega \left( \frac d {\log^2(d)} \right)$ by [Austrin, Khot, and Safra, 2011] assuming the unique games conjecture.

**Question:** What is the strongest hardness of approximation known for the maximum independent set problem as a function of the number of edges $m$? For example, for $m = \log(n)$? is there a known lower bound that depends only on $m$?

Comment: The $n^{1-\epsilon}$ hardness implies $m^{0.5-\epsilon}$ hardness because $m \le n^2$. And there actually exists an approximation algorithm with ratio $m^{0.5}$, because the degeneracy of a graph is at most $d \le m^{0.5}$, and we can always find an independent set of size $n/d$.